# How do I solve Redirect URI is not supported by the client in Discord OAuth2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord, passport.js

Hey there StackOverflow community . I'm implementing a web app which brings out all the possible information of a Discord user. Currently in the backend of my project I use `express | passport | passport-discord` (I am also following a tutorial on YouTube). The relevant code is

`strategies/discord.js`

```js
const DiscordStrategy = require('passport-discord').Strategy;
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('config');
var scopes = ['identify', 'email', 'guilds'];

passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: config.get('discord.clientID'),
    clientSecret: config.get('discord.clientSecret'),
    callbackURL: config.get('discord.redirectURL'),
    scope: scopes
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(profile.id);
    console.log(profile.accent_color);
}));
```

`routes/auth.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('discord'));

router.get('/redirect', passport.authenticate('discord', {
    failureRedirect: '/forbidden'
}), function(req, res) {
    res.send(200) // Successful auth
});

module.exports = router;
```

`config/default.json`

```json
{
    "apiName": "Discord Profiler API",
    "discord": {
        "clientID": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
        "clientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "redirectURL": "localhost:9999/auth/redirect"
    },
    "port": 9999
}
```

The steps when debugging my project where:

1. Hitting the route `/auth` in my browser
2. It takes me to the Discord Authorization page (typically)
3. Clicking the authorize button leads me to this page;

[image: Error gotten from Discord authorization page redirect]

But I have defined all the routes and test them to see if they work, and they all do. If your curious about the YouTube video I got this from this is the [link](https://youtu.be/r_tXkzBgmFc?list=PL_cUvD4qzbkwRMmqlviY0FXL54dEYRNbz)

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late, but always make sure you add "http://" before the localhost and it should work!!

It must be `http` and not `https` since its a local address and can't have a SSL certificate

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer but I switched the library I was using to `discord-oauth2`. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you're missing the scheme part? it should be http://localhost:9999/auth/redirect

Comment: what do you mean by the `scheme`?

Comment: Clicking the authorize button just leaves keeps the page in a endless request cycle but in the console it provides me some values

Comment: I couldn't quite find what the problem was but I recreated the project on a different port and it worked. I switched `passport-js` for `discord-oauth2` and there hasn't been any problem since

Comment: hey @OyedejiOyewole, sorry I missed your follow-up question. Glad you found an alternative fix